# Read Authenticated User Object in ViewSet (Django Rest-Framework)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What i want to do is to filter the queryset for every action on the resource by the authenticated user's ID which is a foreign key on the model, how can I read it when defining the query set?

```
class RunSessionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    """API endpoint for listing and creating sprints."""
    queryset = RunningSession.objects.order_by('createdDate')
    serializer_class = RunSessionSerializer
```

Comment: you can't do it in class definition , override `get_queryset()` method

Answer (score 4):

You should override `get_queryset()` method as described in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-current-user)

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    return RunningSession.objects.filter(foreignkey_field=user).order_by('createdDate')
```